# CSS: styles not applied to two of three <div>'s in JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add CSS to three `<div>` structures with unique IDs. However, as I work on my project, when I make small changes to unrelated CSS, elements will go from being stylized to not being stylized.

Notice the changes between these two versions of the same Fiddle, looking at "Citrus College" :

http://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/zdym681b/1/  - element `#citrus` stylized

http://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/zdym681b/2/ - element `#citrus` unstylized with same CSS for that element.

Trying to see if it worked in less messy example, I created the following modified fork to simplify many of the variables and now a different set of ids are not being stylized which should (Child 1 and Child 2) while Child 3 is (EVen though all through have the same basic CSS stylization other than different margins).

http://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/eedrwL0r/3/

Is this a JSFiddle dependent thing? It is a cross browser issue on my local machine.

Comment: Always post the relevant code in your question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your second fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ebbnormal/zdym681b/2/

Look at the duplicated `}`

```
#saddleback p{
 width=300px;    
}
}
```

I removed it and it works.

Comment: And in your last fiddle there was also one not needed curly bracket I think it was before #child2 in your css and you had a comment with double slashes. CSS requires always /* */ comments. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/eedrwL0r/4/) works.